# solved: Remove Webpack debugging from production for VueJs project

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I created new fresh project with latest VueJS-cli tool. Looks like VueJS CLI is using Webpack 4.43.0.

How to remove that Webpack section, that is visible under browser console/debugging tab?
All code with comments are visible and nothing is striped and uglified.

yarn build shows that it is building for production. Also I tried export NODE_ENV=production

[image]

Thanks in advance

---

I solved.

In : **vue.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    devtool: false
  }
}
```